# how to hide items in render conditions?

Tags: aem

I want to hide default items (for example Screens, Commerce etc) shown in the /aem/start page in Touch UI based on user permission, I do not want to hide completely.

Steps I have done:

1. Overlayed /apps/cq/core/content/nav/screens
2. Added granite:rendercondition node under /apps/cq/core/content/nav/screens

[image]

3. Create a user who does not have read permission under /apps/cq/core/content/nav/screens

Still the user can see those items after login.

Update: I could able to resolve this by adding fake node which is referred in path property of granite:rendercondition node and remove read permission on that fake node.

Comment: why not jusy deny read for that user for the screens and commerce nodes. no render condition necessary.

Comment: It would have been perfect but It does not work either, it works if deny is set  directly under libs, not with overlay

Comment: Right, so deny under libs you’d just be adding a policy to that node and not really impacting site wide functionality. I’d go for it as opposed to a complicated solution.

Comment: Found an alternative solution, updated my question